# Why l.insert(0, i) is slower than l.append(i) in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, list, reverse

I tested two different ways to reverse a list in python.

```
import timeit

value = [i for i in range(100)]
def rev1():
    v = []
    for i in value:
        v.append(i)
    v.reverse()

def rev2():
    v = []
    for i in value:
        v.insert(0, i)

print timeit.timeit(rev1)
print timeit.timeit(rev2)
```

Interestingly, the 2nd method that inserts the value to the first element is pretty much slower than the first one.

```
20.4851300716
73.5116429329
```

Why is this? In terms of operation, inserting an element to the head doesn't seem that expensive.

Comment: Use a deque if you require a linked-list like datastructure: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`insert` is an `O(n)` operation as it requires all elements at or after the insert position to be shifted up by one. `append`, on the other hand, is generally `O(1)` (and `O(n)` in the worst case, when more space must be allocated). This explains the substantial time difference.

The time complexities of these methods are thoroughly documented [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

I quote:

> Internally, a list is represented as an array; the largest costs come from growing beyond the current allocation size (because everything must move), or from inserting or deleting somewhere near the beginning (because everything after that must move).

Now, going back to your code, we can see that `rev1()` is an `O(n)` implementation whereas `rev2()` is in fact `O(n2)`, so it makes sense that `rev2()` will be much slower.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, lists are implemented as arrays. If you append one element to an array, the reserved space for an array is simply expanded. If you prepend an element, all elements are shifted by 1 and that is very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

you can confirm this by reading about python lists online.  Python implements a list as an array, where the size of the array is actually typically larger than the size of your current list.  The unused elements are at the end of the array and represent new elements that could be added to the END of the list, not the beginning.  Python uses a classical amortized cost approach so that on average, appending to the end of the list takes O(1) time if you do a bunch of appends, although occasionally a single append will cause the array to become full so a new larger array needs to be created, and all the data copied to the new array.  On the other hand, if you always insert at the front of the list, then in the underlying array all elements need to be moved over one index to make room for the new element at the beginning of the array.  So, to summarize, if you create a list by doing N insertions, then the total running time will be O(N) if you always append new items to the end of the list, and it will be O(N^2) if you always append to the front of the list.